# How to make a SignalR connection *after* the page loads and reconnect after timeout

Tags: signalr

I have been using SignalR for a while in current versions of chrome, IE and iOS Safari.   I've always noticed that the "spinner" that indicates that the page is loading just continues to spin.

We are now doing some further testing and seeing that the signalR connect is just running until it times out.

/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=XXXX&connectionData="%"5B"%"7B"%"22name"%"22"%"3A"%"22chathub"%"22"%"7D"%"5D&tid=1

In older browsers, this looks to the user as if the page has not finished loading.   Moreover, when the connect finally times out, the application simply stops working (or in some cases throws an error).

I've been able to reproduce this with the tutorial from MS in both the version provided and after upgrading the tutorial to SignalR 2.2.0 and jQuery 2.1.3 via Nuget

Here's the link to the tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

1)  Are there best practices for making a connection to signalR such that the connection doesn't hold up the completion of the initial page rendering?

2)  What about best practices for handling timeouts/reconnects?

Given MS's current tutorial doesn't handle these situations, I'm looking for more real world experiences and possibly some sample code for both scenarios.

Here's MS's tutorial as a starter.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <title>SignalR Simple Chat</title>
     <style type="text/css">
         .container {
             background-color: #99CCFF;
             border: thick solid #808080;
             padding: 20px;
             margin: 20px;
         }
     </style>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div class="container">
         <input type="text" id="message" />
         <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
         <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
         <ul id="discussion"></ul>
     </div>
     <!--Script references. -->
     <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
     <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
     <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
     <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
     <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
     <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
     <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
             // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
             var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
             // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast      messages.
             chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                 // Html encode display name and message.
                 var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                 var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
                 // Add the message to the page.
                 $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                     + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
             };
             // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
             $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
             // Set initial focus to message input box.
             $('#message').focus();
             // Start the connection.
             $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                 $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                     // Call the Send method on the hub.
                     chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(),      $('#message').val());
                     // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                     $('#message').val('').focus();
                 });
             });
         });
     </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Go to the developer tools of your browser, under the network tab, and examine the `/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=` line's request and response headers. Can you post them here please?